# why is getView in ArrayAdapter class executing twice?

Tags: android, view, android-arrayadapter

I have an app that is used by carers to get their rota for a particular day. The user sets a date in a datepicker. This date is passed to an activity called NfcScannerActivity. This activity calls a webservice using that date to get the rota. The rota data is an array. NfcScannerActivity passes this array to GetRota, which is an activity that has an array adapter with which shows the rota data.

All this works fine until in the getView method of GetRota i check if there is no data for a particular day. At this point I toast the user stating this fact and then re-call NfcScannerActivity with another date(hopefully a valid one). If there is no data the getView method seems to execute twice as the user is toasted twice. Why is this?

Snippets from NfcScannerActivity:

```
if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT_ROTA")){

            Log.e(TAG, "next rota action");
            String date = intent.getStringExtra("nextRota");

            getNextRota(date);
        } 




private void getNextRota(String stringExtra) {

    String[] params = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCarerID(), stringExtra}; 
    AsyncGetRota agr = new AsyncGetRota();
    agr.execute(params);

    }







//////////snippet of async result of webservice call
...........
..........
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

           if(isRotaArrayNull == false){

            Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                            GetRota.class);
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putSerializable("rotaArray", rotaArray);

             intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
             startActivity(intent);
        }else{...........
              ...........
```

.

snippet from GetRota, the activity that shows the rota

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }



@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

       Log.e(TAG, "global date in onresume getrota = " + nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime());
         array = (ArrayList<String[]>)getIntent().getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle").get("rotaArray");
        Log.e(TAG, "array size in onresume = " + array.size());

..............
...............





/////////adapter class in getrota

private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent,
                    false);

            TextView startTime = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
            TextView duration = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
            TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
            TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowimagestatus);


            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            rowView.setTag(record);
            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
            Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
            String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {

                recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];

            }


            if(recordItem[9].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Out of range]")){

                Toast.makeText(GetRota.this, "No rota available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nfcscannerapplication.setGobalDateTime(new DateTime());
                //onBackPressed();

                DateTime globalDateTime = nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String formattedglobalDateTime = fmt.print(globalDateTime);
                Intent i = new Intent(GetRota.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("nextRota", formattedglobalDateTime);
                i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA"); 
                startActivity(i);


            }else if(recordItem[0].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("[nodata")){

                Toast.makeText(GetRota.this, "You have no calls", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "you have no calls");

                nfcscannerapplication.setGobalDateTime(new DateTime());
                //onBackPressed();

                DateTime globalDateTime = nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String formattedglobalDateTime = fmt.print(globalDateTime);
                Intent i = new Intent(GetRota.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("nextRota", formattedglobalDateTime);
                i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA"); 
                startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have control over the call of **getView()**. An arrayadapter acts as the bridge between the data and list view. When ever a list view loads, refreshes or there is some scrolling etc, the list view calls the get view method of the array adapter. So you have no control over when the **getView()** is called.
Moreover the getView() is called for each item of the list. So if there are two items who have  `recordItem[0] as no data`, the toast will appear two times.

**recorditem** is an array that is created from a particular position of the **ArrayList**: **list**.

```
recorditem=list.get(position).split();
```

So row1 of the listview will hold a recorditem array, row2 will hold another recorditem array.  Hence if **recorditem[0]** for both the rows have **no data**, then Toast will be shown multiple times.

Comment: Hi, ok thanks for that. recordItem is the array and position 0 is the only position that could have the string "[NODATA". So no other elements in the array will have this particular String. So i was just wondering why the toast message appears twice. The getView must run twice not because 2 elements have "[nodata"

Answer (score 0):

This is because getView is something we cannot control. It is designed this way to consistently refresh views, as decided by the Android system.

Perhaps you can move the toast somewhere else in your code. You can check if there is no rota in onResume or onActivityResult. Generally, you should only be concerned with a specific item in your ArrayList in the getView method.

Comment: I think it would be hard to check elsewhere in the code. The array is a 2 dimensional array. I use the position of the getView to iterate through the outer Array then split the inner array. The app works fine i suppose i'll just put up with 2 toasts, i just wondered why. thanks

Comment: Since you're just checking the [0] and [9] element of each item in your list, I believe you can check it in onCreate to just have a single toast. Give it a try.